# unable to find jvcore.bpi when linking

Tags: c++builder, coff, omf

I use C++Builder (RAD Studio Professional). I have tried installing the JEDI libraries, both though GetIt and GitHub, both giving the same result: "file not found". I tried searching for the file in the system, and found it in the installation files, but linking to that file causes COFF/OMF errors.

Can anyone help me with this, as its a fresh install of RAD and JEDI.  I'm a bit confused.

Comment: Sounds like something you should be contacting the JEDI author about.

Comment: already tried through the news groups and got no response. I don't know any other way to contact them.